# AWS and Mongodb SDKs or APIs for flutter application?

Tags: mongodb, flutter, amazon-web-services, dashboard, mongodb-atlas

I am learning and building a flutter app which is basically data visualization app that is going to display dashboards from MongoDB atlas and a dashboard for AWS EC2-T2 small instance, and for others if I want to add.

How would I go about this? I can build different pages in Flutter to display this dashboards and have proper authentication but I am not sure how to get the data from these services.

I have looked into MongoDB and I found MongoDB charts embedding SDK which is for web application since it's a package in npm but I am trying to build this with flutter. For AWS I found [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/embed-interactive-dashboards-in-your-application-with-amazon-quicksight/) which I think is something I can use but I am not sure how since this also provides an example for Javascript.

Is this something that is possible? I am trying this only for learning purposes as a personal project and expand my knowledge even if it doesn't seem efficient.